# Google login api redirect uri mismatch

Tags: google-signin

This is driving me crazy. The app has been working everyday for exactly a year both as localhost and http.
Then I have registered an https at a reputed CA, got a perfect A score at SSL labs, and also registered the web at Google and then this nonsense that I need to add this to the uri redirect

```
Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid
mymail@gmail.com
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch    

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
https://myweb.com/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

of course I have added the httpS

I am using the AllAuth + Google OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project.
Deleted the old one.
I restarted supervisor
and everything worked again.
This is the kind of things that you never know why, but it works. Maybe upgrading to a production https was another level and wouldn't work with the old project, but... how many frustrations are we enduring through our careers...? Programming has become so complex because there are millions of apps the workings of which you can't control and you are left to your fate.